# Android Countdown Timer with pause and resume not working?

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I'm new to android and making an application in which there is countdown timer with pause and resume toggle-button. Everything is working fine when i pause the timer it's paused but when i resume it didn't resume from where it is paused , it's resume from actual timer running in background.

I did lot of R & D but didn't get the solution. Please someone help me in this.Thanks

Here is my Code:

```
  public class QuizActivityB extends Activity {  

   ToggleButton pauseTB;
   private String setQuestion, testName, time, timecounter;
   private String timeCounterFinish;
   private static double passedTime;
   private static Handler timeHandler = new Handler();
   private static double timeStart = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();;
   private TextView timeLabel;
   private static boolean initialStartTime = false;
   public double testTime;
   private double remaining;

   private Runnable updateTask = new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        double duration = 60 * 1000 * testTime;
        double now = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        remaining = duration - passedTime - (now - timeStart);
        passedTime = now - timeStart + passedTime;
        timeStart = now;

        if (passedTime > 0) {
            int seconds2 = (int) (passedTime / 1000);
            int minutes2 = seconds2 / 60;
            seconds2 = seconds2 % 60;
            if (seconds2 < 10) {
                timeCounterFinish = "" + minutes2 + ":0" + seconds2;
            } else {
                timeCounterFinish = "" + minutes2 + ":" + seconds2;
            }

        }
        if (remaining > 0) {
            int seconds = (int) (remaining / 1000);
            int minutes = seconds / 60;
            seconds = seconds % 60;

            if (seconds < 10) {
                timeLabel.setText("Time Left: " + "" + minutes + ":0"
                        + seconds);
            } else {
                timeLabel.setText("Time Left: " + "" + minutes + ":"
                        + seconds);
            }

            timeHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        } else {
            timeHandler.removeCallbacks(this);
            initialStartTime = false;
            passedTime = 0;
            timeStart = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            PostFinishedData();
            Intent intent = new Intent(QuizActivityB.this,
                    TestAnalysisActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("userID", testID);
            intent.putExtra("time", time);
            intent.putExtra("currentDateandTime", date);
            intent.putExtra("score", finalScore);
            intent.putExtra("finalPercentage", finalPercentage);
            intent.putExtra("totalAttemp", setAttemptedQuestion);
            intent.putExtra("totalQuestions",
                    String.valueOf(totalQuestions));
            intent.putExtra("Wrong", WrongAnswers);
            intent.putExtra("Correct", correctQ);
            intent.putExtra("timecounter", timeCounterFinish);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();

        }
    }
};

    pauseTB = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.pauseBtIV);
    pauseTB.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pausebutton);
    finishBT.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    testName = getIntent().getStringExtra("testName");
    testTime = Integer.parseInt(getIntent().getStringExtra("time"));

   timeLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeDetailsTV);
    timeLabel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    if (!initialStartTime) {
        timeStart = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        initialStartTime = true;
    }

    timeHandler.post(updateTask);

    pauseTB.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                pauseTB.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.resumebutton);

           String timecounter = String.valueOf(passedTime);
                PausePrefEditor.putString("pauseTime", timecounter);
                PausePrefEditor.commit();

                timeHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTask);
                timeHandler = null;
                passedTime = 0;
                initialStartTime = false;
                timeStart = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

            } else {
                // showToastResume();

                String time = pausePreference.getString("pauseTime", "");
                if (time.length() > 0) {
                    double timeSaved = Double.valueOf(time);
                    passedTime = timeSaved;
                    timeHandler = new Handler();
                    timeHandler.post(updateTask);
                }
    }
```

Comment: try to use chronometer

Comment: can you help me in this code as i used this code in many activity. everything is working fine but resume button is not working its resume from background timer but not from where it is paused. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Try To use this code. It will help you.

**Timer.java**

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.ContentValues;

import android.database.Cursor;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Timer extends Activity {
Button b1,b2,b3;
      private TextView t1;

        private long startTime = 0L;

    private Handler customHandler = new Handler();

    long timeInMilliseconds = 0L;
        long timeSwapBuff = 0L;
    long updatedTime = 0L;

    SimpleDateFormat pp;

    String chec;
    String count;
    String name="Timer";
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.timer);
    t1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.timerValue);
    b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.startButton);
    b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.pauseButton);
    b3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                            customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);

               }
                });



                b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        timeSwapBuff += timeInMilliseconds;
                        customHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);

                    }
                });

    }
    public void reset(View v)
    {

     customHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);
       // startTime = 0L;
        timeSwapBuff=0L;
        t1.setText("00:00:00");
    }
    private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {

            public void run() {

                timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;

                updatedTime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;

                int secs = (int) (updatedTime / 1000);
                int mins = secs / 60;
                secs = secs % 60;
               int milliseconds = (int) (updatedTime % 1000);
                    t1.setText("" + mins + ":"
                            + String.format("%02d", secs) + ":"
                            + String.format("%03d", milliseconds));
                    customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
            }

            };
   }
```

**timer.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timerValue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/pauseButton"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="37dp"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:text="00:00:00" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/startButton"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:text="Start" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pauseButton"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/startButton"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Pause" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/pauseButton"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/pauseButton"
        android:text="Reset" 
        android:onClick="reset"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you please figure out my code issue as everything is working fine but resume button is not resuming the timer where it is paused.